# normalize volume in audiofile

Tags: objective-c, ios, ffmpeg

Now I'm creating video with FFMPEG library. I'm receiving audiofile by recording user's voice.
How can I normalize sound. Maybe ffmpeg have tools. Or can you recommend you some algorithm for normalization?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical tool for normalizing audio signals is called... wait for it... [normalize](http://normalize.nongnu.org/). I recommend you use it, either by calling it or by studying its source and doing something similar yourself. Normalizing isn't difficult, you just decide on a maximum safe amplitude and then scale every sample according to that.

Comment: I need **code** or **algorithm**. Does this utility work on iOS?